# Remove all hyperlinks from an excel file using OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

My data source is an excel file that contains a lot of hyperlinks (running into 1000s). I would like to remove all of these programmatically using OpenXML SDK and C#.

My research so far has mostly pointed me to posts that explain how to add a link to Excel/Word files. The solution provided in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6ccfeb55-2bfe-4c63-bd5b-3839c9fb7d1f/how-to-remove-a-hyyerlink-from-excel?forum=oxmlsdk) post gets just the first hyperlink in the document and removes it.

```
           var hyperLinks = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Hyperlinks>().First();

            var hyperRel = worksheetPart.HyperlinkRelationships;

            foreach (Hyperlink item in hyperLinks)
            {
                if(hyperRel.First().Id == item.Id)
                {
                    worksheetPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(item.Id.ToString());
                    item.Remove();
                }

                if (hyperLinks.Count() == 0)
                    hyperLinks.Remove();
            }
```

How do I modify this to enumerate all the links and loop through them? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works for a Worksheet and can be dropped in to replace your above code.  It removes each hyperlink reference relationship and the hyperlink collection.

```
        var hyperLinkCollection = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Hyperlinks>().First();

        if (hyperLinkCollection.Any())
        {
            var hyperLinks = hyperLinkCollection.Descendants<Hyperlink>();

            foreach (var hyperLink in hyperLinks)
            {
                worksheetPart.DeleteReferenceRelationship(hyperLink.Id);
                //remove cell style using hyperLink.Reference
            }
            hyperLinkCollection.Remove();

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
```

**Note**: I did not write code to remove any styling to the cell that contained the hyperlinks.  For example, if your cells that contained hyperlinks styled with blue underlined text, then this formatting will remain after this code is run.

Removing hyperlink styling would involve another method at the commented line above and would involve using the [hyperlink reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.hyperlink.reference(v=office.14).aspx).  But not asked as part of the question and is tougher to do in cases where the cell has more styling than just the hyperlink color (i.e. Table row alternating colors, highlights, etc)

Comment: Thanks! This works. I dont have any formatting (thankfully) so just this is enough for my requriement.